# mgcv access to estimate.gam function

Tags: r, mgcv

I am using the R library `mgcv`

The gam function returns an object with the `edf1` value

```
> g = gam(y~s(x, k = 10, bs = "cr"), data = data, scale = 1)
> g$edf1
(Intercept)      s(x).1      s(x).2      s(x).3      s(x).4      s(x).5      s(x).6      s(x).7      s(x).8 
  1.0000000   0.2417857   0.4744928   0.4667241   0.4347516   0.4107624   0.4136064   0.4288544   0.5315970 
     s(x).9 
  0.5941861 
>
```

I need to understand how this value is computed and so I am reading the code of the `gam()` function.

Inside  `gam()` the result is obtained by another function

```
object <- estimate.gam(G, method, optimizer, control, in.out, 
                         scale, gamma, ...)
```

The problem is that I can not access to the `estimate.gam()` function

```
> estimate.gam
Error: object 'estimate.gam' not found
>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function

Comment: What about `mgcv:::estimate.gam`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the [source code](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/mgcv_1.8-6.tar.gz) and inspect the files. The function `estimate.gam`is stored in the R subdirectory in the file `mgcv.r`.

Comment: The link do not work anymore, but you can go on the mirror Github page: https://github.com/cran/mgcv/blob/master/R/mgcv.r